# Cannot load libR.dylib with JRI on OSX

Tags: r, scala, sbt, dylib, jri

I have a custom compiled R installation. I had to custom compile it in order to use MKL.

In my `build.sbt` I have the following line

`javaOptions += "-Djava.library.path=/Users/me/R-3.3.2/lib:/Users/taylor/Library/R/3.3/library/rJava/jri`

and also:

`fork := true` so `javaOptions` works right.

To test this I fire up `sbt` and attempt to load `jri` with `System.loadLibrary("jri")`. I get the following error:

`java.lang.UnsatisifiedLinkError: /Users/me/R/3.3/library/rJava/jri/libjri.jnilib: dlopen(/Users/me/Library/R/3.3/library/rJava/jri/libjri.jnilib, 1): Library not loaded libR.dylib`

So I went to see with `otool` what it expects -

`otool -L libjri.jnilib` in `/Users/me/Library/R/3.3/library/rJava/jri` has the following in it: (remainder omitted)

```
libjri.jnilib
  libjri.jnilib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
  ...
  libR.dylib (compatibility version 3.3.0, current version 3.3.2)
  ...
```

I thought this looked funny, so I copied `libR.dylib` from `/Users/me/R-3.3.2/lib`into `/Users/me/Library/R/3.3/library/rJava/jri` to see if it was just looking around locally.

Unfortunately I still get the same error.

I'm at a complete loss on what I need to do to make this work, and it has ground my entire project to a halt. Has anyone experienced this and fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that you shouldn't need to re-compile R in order to use MKL, because the CRAN OS X binaries are intentionally shipped such that you can point `libRblas.dylib` to any compatible BLAS implementation - consider reading the R documentation.

As for the error, it seems that you have compiled R without framework support and/or have not installed it, hence `libR` doesn't contain the full path. Also you have likely not used the recommended way to start your Java application use `R CMD`. You can either use

```
install_name_tool -id <libR> <libR>
```

to fix your `libR` manually (where `<libR>` is the full path to your `libR.dylib`), or you can use

```
install_name_tool -change libR.dylib <libR> \
   /Users/me/Library/R/3.3/library/rJava/jri/libjri.jnilib
```

to force `libjri` to pick up you location of `libR`. There are other ways as well, such as setting `DYLD_...` env vars before you start Java or using `R CMD`.